# Microservices architecture, request balancer

Tags: .net, rest, architecture, microservices, amqp

I have this architecture.

1. API gateway as a single entry point and user request balancer (`Ocelot`)
2. And for example, 2 microservices (`data service` and `processor service`), with two instances for each one.

And we have this scenario of communication: User call processor service through api gateway, *Ocelot* balance this request to one of the service instance, `processor service` do some work, but it needs information from `data service` to continue.

#### Question

How I can call `data service` from `processor service` and get a response directly to the same place where I call this service.
My possible solutions:

1. I can use simple REST calls or gRPC, but how I can balance calls between service instances, can I use API gateway that we already using for balancing user requests, or it should be another internal balancer?
2. AMQP(RabbitMQ) also can be solution, in this case, I don't need a balancer because RabbitMQ already has one. But is it possible to return a response in the same place where call was initiated?

Which one is the best solution (pros and cons), or maybe you have other suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Simplest solution

You have stated in your question that you have 2 `processor services` and 2 `data services`. Since the user requests are already load-balanced you might not need to rebalance again between `data service` instances.
Put it simple:

- `Processor Service #1` is connected to `Data Service #1`
- `Processor Service #2` is connected to `Data Service #2`

The main drawback of this approach: it is not fault tolerant. What if `Data Service #1` or `Data Service #2` is overwhelmed or inaccessible? With this setup `Processor Service #1` or `Processor Service #2` is also unusable due to the fact that one of its dependency is temporarily unavailable.

#### Robust solution

As you have indicated in your question there are other solutions as well.

If you would apply an *internal load balancer* in front of the `Data Service` instances then the inaccessibility of an instance would be hidden from the `Processor Service` instances. Also the number of instances are hidden: The `Processor Services` don't know whether there is a single `Data Service` instance (due to the low traffic) or 4 or more instances (due to the high load).

If you would use a messaging system then you coudl decouple the two services from time and space. But that also brings a bunch of new challenges. I would not recommend to introduce a messaging system just because of this problem. [Event-driven architectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event-driven_architecture) are great but very different than RPC-based service integrations.

Answer (score 3):

If you use [Phoesion Glow](https://glow.phoesion.com), a framework designed specifically for creating microservices using dotnet, you can have inter-service communication with the [**Inter**nal **Op**eration mechanism](https://glow-docs.phoesion.com/tutorials/Service_Interop.html).

Do accomplish this you need to

#### 1. Create an API project and defines the prototype of the endpoint :

```cs
namespace Foompany.Services.API.SampleService2.Modules.InteropSample1
{
    public abstract class Actions
    {
        [Interop]
        public static string InteropAction2(string firstname, string surname) => default;
    }
}
```

#### 2. Create your target endpoint (that declares the class above as API)

```cs
namespace Foompany.Services.SampleService2.Modules
{
    [API(typeof(API.SampleService2.Modules.InteropSample1.Actions))]
    public class InteropSample1 : FireflyModule
    {
        [InteropBody]
        public string InteropAction2(string firstname, string surname)
        {
            return $"Hi {firstname} {surname}";
        }
    }
}
```

#### 3. Call/Invoke the remote endpoint from another service :

(Add the API project as project reference)

```cs
[Action(Methods.GET)]
public async Task<string> Action2()
{
    var firstName = "John";
    var surName = "Doe";
    var result = await Call(API.SampleService2.Modules.InteropSample1.Actions.InteropAction2, firstName, surName)
                        .InvokeAsync();
    return $"Service 2 said '{result}'";
}
```

**InvokeAsync** is the **R**emote **P**rocedure **C**all (RPC) mechanism that will send the request to a single instance of a target service. There are other mechanisms as well like Message and Broadcast.

This system also gives you a **strong-typed** API dependency, meaning if something breaking changes in your API, all callers will fail at **compile-time**

### What is happening behind the scenes?

This is all you need to do as developer to have one service communicating with another service. Behind the scenes the Phoesion Glow **Kaleidoscope** is a message broker, like RabbitMQ (that is also based on an AMQP-like protocol) that will automatically create the appropriate Exchanges/Queues/Bindings and when you call the other service from your code Phoesion Glow will also handle the service-discovery/routing/serialization/deserialization/binding automatically.

For more you can read the [Documentation](https://glow-docs.phoesion.com/tutorials/Service_Interop.html) or have a look at the full [Sample Code](https://github.com/Phoesion/Glow-Samples/tree/master/2_Interop)

## Load balancing

Phoesion Glow **Prism** is the entrypoint in your Cloud. *(like Ocelot in your example)*. **Prism** as a Web-Server that will handle the incoming request but together with **Kaleidoscope** *(Service-Bus)* will **Load Balance** the request to best suited **Firefly** *(Service Host)* that is running your **business logic** code. When deploying to your **Glow** setup all entities are informed about the services and routing instructions automatically so you don't need to manually configure/update your gateway.

## Architecture

Here is a top-level view of the architecture.
[Architecture Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vLuRh.png)

For more info about the [architecture you can read this](https://glow-docs.phoesion.com/articles/Architecture_Overview.html).

*Disclosure : I am a developer of Phoesion Glow*